# How does gmail's sign out all other sessions work?

Tags: networking, cookies, web, gmail, mac-address

I want to know how to identify computers individually from a web server. logged in one computer in gmail I can log out other gmail session, when even in the same network? How does gmail do that? MAC address will not be an answer I guess. what is the best way to identify computers?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the internal workings of GMail.  But you can use [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to track individual sessions.